# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'torch' or 'matmul'

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torchvision

I am having attribute errors with my code. I have numpy version '1.25.1', python 3.10 and torch 2.0.1.

When using transform and target_transform, I was following this pytorch tutorial (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/transforms_tutorial.html)

```
import numpy as np
import torch
...
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Lambda
..
# defining the class
class EmbeddingDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, embedding_fp, transform=None, target_transform=None):

        with open(embedding_fp, "rb") as fIn:
            stored_data = pickle.load(fIn)
            stored_labels = stored_data['labels']
            stored_embeddings = stored_data['embeddings']
        self.X = stored_embeddings 
        self.y = stored_labels.to_numpy()
        
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        X = self.X[idx]
        y = self.y[idx]

        if self.transform:
            X= self.transform(X)
           # X = torch.tensor(x).float()
        if self.target_transform:
            y = self.target_transform(y)
            # y = torch.tensor(y).float().unsqueeze(1) 
        return X, y
        
# instantiating a class
train_data = EmbeddingDataset('embeddings_db_train.pkl', transform=ToTensor(),
    target_transform=Lambda(lambda y: torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.float).scatter_(0, torch.tensor(y), value=1)))
X_train = train_data.X
y_train = train_data.y

test_data = EmbeddingDataset('embeddings_db_test.pkl', transform=ToTensor(),
    target_transform=Lambda(lambda y: torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.float).scatter_(0, torch.tensor(y), value=1)))
X_test = test_data.X
y_test = test_data.y

type(X_test)
numpy.ndarray

# defining some functions
    def plain_accuracy(self, X_test, y_test):
        # evaluate accuracy of the model on
        # the plain (x_test, y_test) dataset
        w = torch.tensor(self.weight)
        b = torch.tensor(self.bias)
        out = torch.softmax(X_test.matmul(w) + b).reshape(-1, 1)
        correct = torch.abs(y_test - out) < 0.5
        return correct.float().mean() 
...   
        def softmax(self, enc_x):
        val_out = enc_x.T.dot(self.weight) + self.bias
        val_expo = np.array([EncryptedLR.our_exp(x) for x in val_out])
        val_pred = np.array([x * EncryptedLR.goldschmidt(x, M=1/EncryptedLR.GOLDSCHMIDT_CONST, n=EncryptedLR.GOLDSCHMIDT_ITER) for x in val_expo])

        return val_pred

# error with the line
out = torch.softmax(X_test.matmul(w)+b).reshape(-1,1)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'matmul'

# also an error
X_test_ = X_test.torch.tensor(X).float()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'torch'
```

I have two questions.   first, I do not quite understand why my X_test is still a numpy array, I thought it would be converted to a tensor when I am instantiating/creating the test_data object from my class? second, I do not know how to fix the Attribute Errors.
Can someone advise me what I need to change in my code.

Comment: Is your `ToTensor` transform the one from torchvision https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html?

Comment: When you're calling `X_test = test_data.X` it isn't using the `__getitem__` method, so the tranform `ToTensor` is not getting applied and you're just getting back the original numpy array that your `EmbeddingDataset` was initialised with. To have the `__getitem__` be called you need to do e.g., `X_test, y_test = test_data[0]`.

Comment: I have updated my question. I used 'from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor'.

Comment: with test_data[0], I am getting 'ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 1 dimensions.'

Comment: Rather than using `ToTensor` try just using `torch.from_numpy`, i.e., `test_data = EmbeddingDataset('embeddings_db_test.pkl', transform=torch.from_numpy, ...)`

Comment: I have tried to use  for X_test=torch.tensor(x).float() which converts it ok into a tensor with shape torch.Size([209527, 384]).  however, I have labels for y_test (e.g. 1, 2, 3,4). if I do torch.from_numpy(y) I get the shape torch.Size([209527]).  if I do y = torch.tensor(y).float() then I get shape torch.Size([209527, 384]). I need the shape of y as  torch.Size([209527, 1]) - how can I achieve that?  thank u.

Comment: If `y` has a shape `torch.Size([209527])`, you can reshape it to have a singleton final dimension in a couple of ways, e.g., `y = y.unsqueeze(-1)` or `y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], 1)`, both which which shoud result in the shape of `y` being `torch.Size([209527, 1])`.

Comment: ok, I have re-written     def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        X = self.X[idx]
        X = torch.tensor(X).float()
        y = self.y[idx]
        y= torch.tensor(y).float().unsqueeze(0)  ..  Now, when I do  X_test, y_test = test_data[0] , I get X_train shape of torch.Size([384]) and y_train shape of torch.Size([384]). Which does not seem to right. :/

Comment: got it. I moved         self.X = stored_embeddings 
        self.X = torch.tensor(X).float().unsqueeze(0)
        self.y = stored_labels.to_numpy()
        self.y= torch.tensor(y).float().unsqueeze(0) to the def __init__() from  def __getitem__() and got the correct dimentions.   hopefully thats the right way to do it.

Comment: `X_test.matmul` - `matmul` is a numpy function, not an array method.  `np.dot` works both ways, but not `matmul`.  Also an array does not have a `torch` method.  When you get an attribute error, either the class of the object is wrong, or the choice of attribute is.  Keep the numpy docs at hand so you can check things like this.